# Parse - Get Number of Installations

Tags: python, api, rest, installation, parse-platform

Is there a way to force using a master-key when I make a find operation on the installation collection?

Here's what I'm doing. I'm trying to get the total number of installations.

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)

params = urllib.urlencode({"count": 1, "limit": 0 })

connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/installations?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "app id",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "rest api key"
})

result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

And this is the json response I get.

```
{
    code: 119,
    error: "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your master-key to your connection.request:

```
connection.request('GET', '/1/installations?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "app id",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "rest api key", 
       "X-Parse-Master-Key": "the master key"
})
```